# shaded frame not working in TexStudio

Tags: macros, framed

I'm using TexStudio 2.6.6 and MikTex portable. I'm trying to build the example CV from here: http://www.njohnston.ca/2008/12/latex-cv-template/

The problem is that I get a lott of "Undefined Control sequence" and "Missing control sequence inserted errors for all \resheading lines

The editor gives error indications for \FrameSep and \begin{shaded} and \end{shaded} here:

```
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}
}
```

The framed package is installed. According to all the documentation I found, there is nothing fancy going on, so I'm a bit out of ideas what to try.

I hope you can verify and maybe solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `\ressubheading` contained in the CV template file  [`cv_temp.tex`](http://www.nathanieljohnston.com/cv_temp.tex):

```
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.5in}{l@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
```

requires the `array` package, so simply load it in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
```

Comment: Briljant. Could you also describe how you checked for this dependency and how I can prevent such errors in the future?

Comment: @Jeroen the error messages on the output console pointed to `@{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}` so the culprit was there; the `array` package offers a more sophisticated version for the `@{...}` syntax so loading it fixed the problem. However, to be honest, it is not clear to me why tha author of the template was trying to achive including `\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}` in the declaration.